# Calculus of a limit

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ bilinear. Show that $lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{|f(h,k)|}{|(h,k)|}=0$.

I want to prove this without to prove $Df(a,b)(x,y) = f(a,y) + f(x,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is bilinear then you have that

$f(h,k)=f(h_{1},\ldots, h_{n},k_{1},\ldots, k_{m})=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{m}h_{i}k_{j}f(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0,0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$

So there exist $M>0$ such that

$|f(h,k)|\leq M\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{m}|h_{i}k_{j}|\leq M |(h,k)|^{2}$.

Whence it follows your result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.